# Jquery Plugin: ba-replacetext, Javascript working but needing help.. RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to remove text from a dropdown menu using a Jquery plugin called ba-replacetext.  It's ALMOST working, but could use a bit of tweeking.  Please help me out as I am still learning Jquery / JS programming.  Thanks!
(trying to remove ONLY the following phrases:  "less $2,800.00" and "less $200.00")

**HTML Source:**

```
<select id="ct100_mainContent_productOption_1000193123" name="optionId">
<option value="">- Select Deposit or Full Tuition -</option>
<option value="1000918521" selected="selected">Full Tuition (One Time Payment of $3,000)</option><option value="1000918519">Deposit Only ($200 Initial Payment) - less $2,800.00</option><option value="1000918520">Remaining Balance ($2,800 Following Deposit) - less $200.00</option></select>
```

**Jquery Function:**

```
    $(function(){
  $('#ct100_mainContent_productOption_1000193123').ready(function(){
  $('#ct100_mainContent_productOption_1000193123 *').replaceText(/less \$(2,8|2)00\.00/gi, '');
  $('#ct100_mainContent_productOption_1000193123 *').replaceText( /-+/gi, '' );
 });
});
```

Result of this code is that only the word less is removed not the entire phrase less $2,800.00.  I can't get it to work, perhaps because I am using the wrong Regexp?  Thoughts?   Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly "less $2,800.00" and "less $200.00" then you would need something along the lines of:

```
replaceText(/less \$(2,8|2)00\.00/gi, '')
```

Here the `(2,80|2)` will match either of the two variants above, but nothing else.  If instead you want to match any for of money statement you would need:

```
replaceText(/less \$[0-9,.]+/gi, '')
```

Also, you will want to account for the "-" before your "less" since that will be dangling after replacement.  Of course you will need to experiment with your exact needs for which I would recommend searching with terms "javascript regex" and find a reference that works best for you.  Mine is [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: I changed the code at the top.   Thanks Brett, still learning but this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note: I actually found it better to use the .ready event instead of onhover..  Like I said, still learning.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, your regex doesn't say anything about the dollar amount. `\bless\b` means "match a word boundary, then the word 'less', then another word boundary". You want something like `\bless \$[0-9,.]+`. You can test your regular expressions at sites like [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), and it sounds like you might want to read an intro to regexes generally.

Small disclaimer: I don't know anything about ba-replacetext.

Answer (score 0):

u can use on all 'less' text globally ..

```
$('#ct100_mainContent_productOption_1000193123 option').each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var i = html.indexOf('less');
    if (i > -1) {                    
        $(this).html(html.substring(0, i));
    }
});
```